# Why does 'show user' command gives error in C# where as works in Oracle's SQL Plus?

Tags: c#, oracle

I am using Oracle 12c. When I open my Sql Plus (after user login) and type show user, I get an output showing my current user name. But when I pass same query from command text in c# I get an error stating Invalid Query. 
Is there a way out to get user name from oracle in c# also how to get last login (Photo attatched) from oracle in c#.

Date and time in SQL Plus:
(http://i60.tinypic.com/6549s9.png)

Error in c# program:
(http://i59.tinypic.com/2lc5mb.png)

```
    private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String connectionString = "Data Source = (DESCRIPTION =" +
    "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))" +
    "(CONNECT_DATA =" +
      "(SERVER = DEDICATED)" +
      "(SERVICE_NAME = BU)" +
    ")" +
  "); User Id =" + UsernameTextBox.Text + ";" + "password =" + PasswordTextBox.Text + ";";

            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            con.Open();

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "show user;";
            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            dr.Read();

            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Login Sucessful! \n", dr.GetString(0), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
        catch (OracleException ex) {
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Unable to connect to database. \n\nException Details: " + ex.Message , "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
    }``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a valid query you can use:

```
select user from dual
```

You can't use `show user`, because that's a SQL*PLUS-specific command.  It's not a valid Oracle SQL query.

**EDIT**

As for getting the last login information, starting with Oracle 12c, you can get it like this:

```
select last_login
  from dba_users
 where username = user
```

... but you need to have the `DBA` role to be able to run that.

Comment: Thank You for such a quick response but now I am getting an error saying 'SQL command not properly ended' (Picture attached: http://i58.tinypic.com/30t72nl.png).

Comment: @AzeemUllah try removing the final ";"

Comment: @aquinas: oops, that's right. ADO.NET doesn't expect the semi colons to be there.

Comment: Thank you aquinas and sstan. 
I would also like to clear that by sstan's last line: "... but you need to have the DBA role to be able to run that" he means I should be logged in as System User to get that login information right?

Comment: @Azeem: To query `DBA_...` dictionary views you need the `DBA` role.  `SYSTEM` is one such user.  But you can (and probably should) create other users and grant them the `DBA` role if necessary.

Comment: User name should be in single quotation and you should be logged in as system user. Thank you one more time sstan.

Example:
SELECT username,last_login FROM dba_users WHERE username='SCOTT';

Comment: Granting SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE gives rights to view DBA_* views without other DBA role privileges. And the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY privilege may also work. http://hemantoracledba.blogspot.com/2014/02/the-difference-between-select-any.html